# How to order resources to be used inside create_resources?

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have to create resource like

```
files_list = {
    '/a': {ensure => 'file'},
    '/a/b': {ensure => 'link', target => '/d/e', require[File['/a']]}
}

create_resources(file, files_list)
```

It gives an error, that dependency File['/a'] is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it should be `require => File[/a]`, the same syntax as usual.

Second, you are ensuring that `/a` is a file, not a directory. That means that creating a symlink at `/a/b` will fail, since it is not a directory.

Finally, you do not need to specify a dependency at all, since puppet handles [auto-requiring](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html#autorequire) parent directories. In other words, a file `/a/b/c` will automatically require both `/a` and `/a/b` if they are declared.

Comment: Yeah removing quotes helped. Thanks for the answer.